# how to select columns from a pandas dataframe in python based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, filtering

I have a dataframe (t_df_noNA) with over 4000 columns. I wanted to select all columns where the values have atleast one value over 70.
i am using the following code for extracting columns having values above cutoff (70)

```
filtertdf = t_df_noNA[t_df_noNA.columns[(t_df_noNA > 70).any()]]
```

the code works but selects columns having atleast one value above 70. 
But now I have to select columns that have atleast 4 values over 70. How do I handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do:

```
cols = df.columns[(df > 4).sum().gt(4)].tolist()
filter_df = df[cols]
```

Comment: i have used used your code according to my dataframe and it is giving me the desired result. but i have not understand the .sum() function. can u please explain me a bit more.  ````filtertdf = t_df_noNA[t_df_noNA.columns[( t_df_noNA > 70).sum().gt(3)].tolist()]````

Comment: `.sum()` basically counts the number of True/False in each column i.e. how many values from each column are greater than 4.